# iOS GA4 Analytics displays page locations instead of page title

Tags: ios, cordova, google-analytics-4

Recently, while analyzing user data, we noticed that iOS devices display page locations as titles, even when the correct title is set. Is this the expected behaviour in iOS?

```
    function setGoogleAnalyticsConfig(measurementId, eventUrl, pageTitle) {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', measurementId);
  gtag('event', 'page_view', {
    page_location: eventUrl,
    page_title: "Page Title from iOS"
  });
}
```

Data Layer contains the both page title and location.
[image: Data Layer]